# Replay series of events with timestamps using RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

If I have an array of events that include a utc timestamp and event data like as follows:
[{utcts: , data: , ... ];

how would you use RxJS to "replay" those events with the correct time differentials between each item in the array?  Assume the array is ordered by the utcts field so the first item has the lowest value.

here is a very basic set of data to get started:

```
var testdata = [
  {utcts: 1, data: 'a'},
  {utcts: 4, data: 'b'},
  {utcts: 6, data: 'c'},
  {utcts: 10, data: 'd'}
];
```

Assume the utcts is just the number of seconds from the start of replaying the event which starts at 0 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Use `delayWhen` to give you timed replay.

Since utcts given is relative (not absolute) time, don't need to refresh the timestamp inside the data object.

I have added a timestamp to the console log so we can see the elapsed output time.

Note the extra few milliseconds is typical of rxjs process time.

```js
console.clear()

const testdata = [
  {utcts: 1, data: 'a'},
  {utcts: 4, data: 'b'},
  {utcts: 6, data: 'c'},
  {utcts: 10, data: 'd'}
];

const replayData = (data) => Rx.Observable.from(data)
  .delayWhen(event => Rx.Observable.of(event).delay(event.utcts * 1000))

// Show replay items with output time (in milliseconds)
const start = new Date()
replayData(testdata)
  .timestamp()
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x.value, 'at', x.timestamp - start, 'ms'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Ref [delayWhen](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delayWhen), [timestamp](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timestamp.html)

---

This also works, arguably simpler, not sure which is best.

`mergeMap()` flattens the inner observable, which is necessary to apply the delay.

```js
const replayData = (data) => Rx.Observable.from(data)
  .mergeMap(event => Rx.Observable.of(event).delay(event.utcts * 1000))
```

Comment: I've been fiddling a bit with you method, but haven't been able to get it to work. I updated the question with some example data for 4 events that I would like to get replayed 1,4,6 and 10 seconds after start.

Answer (score 0):

Rough pseudo (comes out of my head directly without running to verify) might be something similar to

```
Observable.scan((acc, value) => ({
   delay: delay === NaN ? value.utcts - delay,
   value
 }), { delay: NaN, value: null })
.mergeMap(({delay, value}) => Observable.from(value).delay(delay))
```

`scan` operator is similar to `reduce`, but emits intermediate values. Using that compute diff between times to get delay those values, then emit values per given delayed time. There are couple of other approaches could work in same way.

Comment: it seems like this is close, but I can't quite get it to work. I've added some sample data to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in https://rxviz.com (copy-paste there):

```
const { delay, mergeMap } = RxOperators;
const { from, Observable, of } = Rx;

const testdata = [
  {utcts: 0.2, data: 'a'},
  {utcts: 2.0, data: 'b'},
  {utcts: 2.8, data: 'c'},
  {utcts: 4.0, data: 'd'}
];
from(testdata).pipe(
  mergeMap(event => of(event).pipe(
    delay(event.utcts * 1000)
  ))
)
```