# RXJS: Scheduler with custom time/clock based on array with timestamps

Tags: node.js, rxjs, scheduler, rxjs6

I have some observables that use time based operators like delay, bufferTime, etc. while waiting for real-time events and have recorded these events and would like to run the code against the recorded data instead of against the live data.

My current thought is that it might be possible to write a custom scheduler that is tick-based with an internal clock that's driven by the recorded events' timestamps so I can just loop over the events and the time-based observables will emit bases on that internal clock. Then I can test my software against a longer period of time without having to wait for that time to actually pass.

I have tried to fiddle around with schedulers but wasn't able to figure it out so far.. Is this something that can be achieved at all?

The code runs on nodejs, so there are no browser limitations (if there are any) that I have to take into account.

**EDIT**:
The ticks have their own timestamps. The observables currently use `scheduler.now` when they need the current time, which should be in sync with the current tick's time (default scheduler being used is the asyncScheduler in the real time version).

- The software will perform some actions, depending on the incoming events, that will cause it to do a request (which I'd like to mock with cold observables that emit after a random, reasonable delay).
- The requests are going to be rate limited, so it's essential that the software does not do anything while the internal loading state is true when the next tick is scheduled (unless the time of the tick advances the time enough so that's more than the request's delay)
- TestScheduler is not an option as it only works with marbles (as far as I can tell)
- Conventional rxjs operators to create a tick queue is not what I'm looking for (I already have that), what I think I need is a scheduler with some kind of virtual time concept (based on the ticks' timestamps) so I can loop through the queue without having to wait any actual time until I can proceed to the next tick. I'm not too familiar with the VirtualTimeScheduler, but from what I've read so far, I'd first have to create a task queue and then run it (when calling the scheduler's `flush` method). Creating the task queue is the issue here, because it'd need to be dynamic, dependent on the input data (used for the ticks) and the resulting behavior of the requests and the rate limiting

Comment: there is already a test scheduler in rxjs that does something similar. however in you specific case (since you have a set of recorded timestamps) you rather want to create an static observable that replays your recorded events when subscribed to it. Sort your events by their timestamp in ascending order. The first event would be emitted immediately and all subsequent events would be delayed by the timestamp distance to the first event. Just try to implement it, if you have trouble with that you could post your code here (update your question) and we will help you.

Comment: btw. a similar question was already asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973157/replay-series-of-events-with-timestamps-using-rxjs

Comment: @Mohammer did you figure it out?

Comment: @Dams yes and no.. I haven't been able to do it with a scheduler, but zone.js by angular hijacks the event loop and makes async code run synchronously. That actually works and seems a lot better than what I was trying to do